# C# make my application a background process

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm looking to make my C# application into a background process, basically I want to hide my application from the main tab in tast manager, It's a updater app for my main application, a VPN

Comment: Are you looking for a [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: ive tried disabling task manager, and other codes to hide a process from task manager, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: So do you want to hide your process from Task Manager?

Comment: yes, I do want to hide my process from task manager

Answer (score 1):

Don't show any type of GUI. A process is automatically a background process without a GUI.

`WinForms` and `WPF` are types of GUI.

To create one just use this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Your code...
    }
}
```

With visual studio:

> 1. Create a Winforms project.
> 2. Delete any `Form` classes, like `Form1`.
> 3. Remove the startup `Form` in the project settings.
> 4. Go to `Program.cs`.
> 5. Remove all lines in the `Main` method, starting with `Application`.
>
> Then put your code in the main method.

Comment: how do I make it with no GUI?

Comment: Just put your code in the main method. And don't allow any type of GUI to show.

Comment: I have done all of the steps you have provided, but I'm not sure what your talking about in step #3

Comment: Set Startup form to (Not Set)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building a windows service if this is a backround process that you want to run continously.

The [Topshelf project](http://topshelf-project.com/) can make this really easy for you.
Just install the nuget package and use it like so:

```
public class TownCrier
{

    readonly Timer _timer;
    public TownCrier()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000) {AutoReset = true};
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("It is {0} and all is well", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
    public void Stop() { _timer.Stop(); }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 //1
        {
            x.Service<TownCrier>(s =>                        //2
            {
               s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier());     //3
               s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());              //4
               s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());               //5
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();                            //6

            x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");        //7
            x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                       //8
            x.SetServiceName("Stuff");                       //9
        });                                                  //10
    }
}
```

This code example is from their [quick start guide](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html)